# dll Dependency unwanted with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, linker, cuda

I am using visual studio 2010. 
Before starting my project, I installed cuda SDK 4.2. 
After that, I installed opencv 2.4.2. In my project, I'm using only opencv and it works correctly. However, when I try to run my program on another computer it tells me that cuda dll (like cudart32_42_9.dll, npp32_42_9.dll and nvcuda.dll) are needed. I don't use at all cuda and do no reference in my project property to cuda. I would like to know how to remove those dependency. I don't understand why visual studio add dll I don't use.

Comment: You may be using the GPU version of the OpenCV lib files. On the other computer, check the path of lib files. Make sure its not pointing to the gpu folder in the OpenCV directory.

Comment: @sgar91 I checked the opencv dll dependency with dependency walker and I think I built the opencv with cuda. So even if I don't use cuda, the opencv dll has the dependency. I guess I have no choice than giving the cuda dll with the program. On the other computer, there is no opencv installed, I give opencv dll with the program.

Comment: instead of building opencv yourself, why don't you download the pre-built OpenCV from sourceforge. It contains both cuda and non-cuda versions of the binaries. Just copy the non-cuda version of the dll to the other computer and it will work.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.2/OpenCV-2.4.2.exe/download

Comment: @sgar91 Effectively, it works. I just had to add tbb.dll from the common folder but the big advantage is that now, computer that can't run cuda can now run my program.

Comment: yeah, that's because the pre-built non cuda version of OpenCV is built with Intel Thread Building Blocks.

Comment: @sgar91: Can you promote your comment to an answer? Does OpenCV have a fall-back to use TBB if a GPU is not available? The CUDA runtime DLLs are redistributable and not dependent on having a CUDA driver, designed so that you can check if a CUDA device exists and fall-back if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-built OpenCV 2.2 onwards, comes with 2 versions of the binaries (dlls).

The dlls in the **\build\gpu** directory are the superset and are built with CUDA support. Therefore, to use them you require the CUDA Runtime dlls (cudart, npp etc). These binaries are required if you want to use the GPU functionality of OpenCV. These may also be used to check if you have a GPU present in your system or not.

The other version of dlls which are present in the x86 or x64 folder in the **build** directory of OpenCV, are built without CUDA support (although a gpu dll is also present in that directory). You don't need cuda dlls to use these binaries.

Both of these versions are built with Intel Thread Building Blocks support, and so require tbb_debug.dll and tbb.dll for Debug and Release configurations respectively. So if you use the CPU functions of OpenCV, they will be TBB Accelerated.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to know wich function in openCV use Cuda ? I guess the Cuda build is much faster than the non-Cuda.

Comment: The GPU functionality is available only in the C++ interface of OpenCV. All the functions, which are inside the namespace cv::gpu are gpu accelerated, and use CUDA. First, you have to #include gpu.hpp in the source file where you have to use them.

Comment: Its not necessary that CUDA build should be faster. It depends on the hardware present in the system. e.g it will be an unfair comparison if you compare Tesla C2070 with Core 2 Duo. But you can really say that gpu is fast if you compare C2070 with Core i7 2600K :p .

Comment: I didn't use cv::gpu but only cv::core, improc, highgui and video but those dll needed cuda dll. So I thought that they used cuda.

Comment: @sgar91: I guess you mixed up the processor names: Core i7 2600K has ~60 GFlops and is a better candidate for comparison with Tesla than Core 2 Duo which has only ~20 GFlops. Both are much slower than Tesla C2070 (~1 TFlop) on simple arithmetic operations, but can be faster when there're lots of conditionals in the algorithm.

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins I think you misunderstood.  If you compare CUDA against an older, slower intel processor, that might be a less "fair" comparison, than if you compared it with a newer, more recent intel processor, and you still found C2070 to be faster.

Comment: Yep, I got your point. Yet sgar91's examples don't illustrate his idea that whether CUDA is faster or not depends on the hardware. Consider his first two sentences alone: after "e.g" one would expect to see examples - which processors are faster and which are slower than GPU.   
Those two parts - before 'e.g' and after - make sense on their own, but they don't tie together :)